# HTML table doesn't display correctly in Outlook

Tags: html, outlook

I am creating HTML table in Outlook email to make it look like a template example like this,
[image]

However the one I created isn't match like it should be. There are 3 issues,

- first **Manage Information Technology** at top right is shift down instead of suppose to be equal position as black box logo like an example template from above.
- Second, **ServiceNow - Release Notes** aligned on left instead of center even though I already have `align="center"` in `<td>`.
- Third, the black border line locate below orange banner disappear but the snippet code and the outlook preview is showing it but the actual outlook is not.

Here is 2 images of incorrect outlook display,

[image]
[image]

```html
<table style="height: 643px;" width="772" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr style="border-style: none none solid none;">
            <td colspan="2"><span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times;"><img id="logo" style="float: left;" title="" src="toolbar-logo.png" alt="" width="127" height="44" /></span></td>
            <td colspan="2">
                <p style="text-align: right;"><font face="calibri, times"><span style="font-size: 18.6667px;"><font color="red"><strong>Manage Information Technology</strong></font></span>
                    </font>
                </p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-style: none none solid none;">
            <td colspan="4" align="center"><font size="7" face="calibri"><strong>ServiceNow - Release Notes</strong></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="border-style: none none solid none;">
            <td colspan="4" align="center"><img id="dss-banner" src="DSSbanner.png" alt="" width="100%" height="161" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="background: none; border-bottom: 4px solid #000000; height: 2px; width: 100%; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;" colspan="4"><span style="font-family: 'times new roman', times;">&nbsp;</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'calibri', times;">Team,</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><span style="font-family: 'calibri', times;"><span style="font-size: 12pt;">The following capabilities and improvements have successfully been promoted to the production ServiceNow instance through "${short_description}" on ${mail_script:release.stories.email.date}.<br />The release notes have also been added in the <a href="/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0011175">Release Notes Knowledge Article</a> per standard process.</span></span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>${mail_script:release.stories.email}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: 'calibri', times;">Thank you,<br />Service Management</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Can anyone point where where possible reason why it didn't match correctly?

Comment: Perhaps try removing the colspan from the first row and changing the others to 2 instead of 4.  Then try aligning using vertical-align on the table cell

Comment: @Pete I just try that you suggested and added `<td valign="middle">` but nothing change.

Comment: have you considered trying to use Flex? I've never had luck with tables in emails, but Flex has always worked as expected